# Showing a set limit equality $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^k_n=A^k$ where $A^k_n=\{t\in I:\inf_{m\geq n}f_m(t)\geq 1/k\}$ and $f$ is non-negative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$  be some fixed interval and $\left(f_m\right)_{m=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of non-negative functions defined on $I$. Define the sets $A^k_n = \{x \in I:\inf_{m\geq n}f_m(x) \geq 1/k\}$ and $A^k = \{x \in I:\lim\inf_{m\to \infty}f_m(x) \geq 1/k\}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I am trying to show rigorously that $\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty A_n^k = A^k$. I have already shown that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^k \subset A^k$ and that any $x \in A^k$ with $\lim\inf_{m\to\infty}f_m(x) > 1/k$ also belongs to $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^k$ by using the definition of limit inferior. Currently I am stuck with the case $\lim\inf_{m\to\infty}f_m(x) = 1/k$. Intuitively it makes sense to me that such an $x$ should also belong to $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^k$ since we may take arbitrarily large starting index $N \in \mathbb{N}$ to reduce the possible discrepancy between $\inf_{m\geq N}f_m(x)$ and $\lim\inf_{m\to\infty}f_m(x)$ by an arbitrary amount (as $\lim\inf_{m\to\infty}f_m(x) \geq \inf_{m\geq N}f_m(x)$).

What I am struggling with is to write this idea down rigorously. To be more specific, I am not that comfortable with set theoretical limits and somehow pulling out (and putting back in) set constructor predicates, which is most likely what is needed in this case.

Comment: If you take $f_m(x) = \max(0, {1 \over k} - { 1\over m})$ then $A_n^k$ will be empty but $A^k$ will be the universal set.

Comment: @copper.hat In your example the $k$ in $f_m$'s definition is fixed, right? So couldn't we just take some $K > k$ so that in $A^K_n$ for large enough $n > K$ we have $f_m(x) = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{n}  > \frac{1}{K}$?

Comment: In my example, $f_m(x) < { 1\over k}$ for any $m,k \in \mathbb{N}$. So $A_n^k = \emptyset$. And $\liminf_m f_m(x) = { 1 \over k}$ so $A^k$ is the entire space.